# Output row with no duplicated date based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

To produce an effort forecast I need to combine the tables of "booked time" (here: sapactivities) and "planned time" (here: plannedactivities). The output shall contain the total daily hours spent by unique day/resource/notification combination, with giving priority to "booked" over "planned" time.

```
SELECT date_format(result.CurrentDate, '%a, %d.%m.%Y'), 
   result.Resource, result.Notification, result.Hours, result.Effort 
FROM
(SELECT sapactivities.start AS 'CurrentDate',
        sapactivities.activitytext AS 'Resource',
        sapactivities.notification AS 'Notification',
        SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start,end)/60) AS 'Hours',
        'Booked' AS 'Effort'
    FROM work.sapactivities 
    GROUP BY sapactivities.notification,sapactivities.activitytext,sapactivities.start

UNION ALL

SELECT plannedactivities.activitydate AS 'CurrentDate',
    /*CONCAT_WS(' ',resource.firstname,resource.lastname) AS 'Resource',*/
    resource.sapActivityText AS 'Resource',
    notification.notification AS 'Notification',
    plannedactivities.hours AS 'Hours',
    'Planned' AS 'Effort'
FROM work.plannedactivities
LEFT JOIN work.notification ON plannedactivities.idNotification = notification.id
LEFT JOIN work.resource ON plannedactivities.idResource = resource.id) AS result
GROUP BY result.Resource, result.Notification, DATE (result.CurrentDate), 
  CASE WHEN result.Effort = 'Booked' THEN 'Booked' ELSE 'Planned' END
ORDER BY result.Resource,result.CurrentDate ASC;
```

But still I get duplicated rows for day/resource/notification with "Booked" and "Planned" effort. I tried multiple approaches on the outer GROUP BY clause, but don't get the result I am looking for...any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your CASE be on the SELECT statement like this?

```
SELECT 
date_format(result.CurrentDate, '%a, %d.%m.%Y'), 
result.Resource, result.Notification, result.Hours, 
(CASE WHEN result.Effort = 'Booked' THEN 'Booked' ELSE 'Planned' END) 
FROM ...
```

And by the way, you are only left join one column, shouldn't you be doing the left joins on both columns before the union?

Hope it helps... It would be a lot better if we had real info to try it :D

Comment: Works perfectly when moving the CASE into SELECT statement, thx. Your comment about the LEFT JOINS I didn't really get - I think both JOINs are executed as there is a closing bracket behind the second one. Also in the result Resource column is properly given

Comment: Glad i could help :) Didn't notice the bracket behind the second one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally it can be done with ROW_NUMBER emulation see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ . Provided `'Booked'<'Planned'` and `Hours` never exceed 1000000 this trick will do

```
Select CurrentDate, Resource, Notification, min(Hours) MOD 100000, min(Effort) 
FROM (

    SELECT sapactivities.start AS 'CurrentDate',
            sapactivities.activitytext AS 'Resource',
            sapactivities.notification AS 'Notification',
            1000000 + SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start,end)/60) AS 'Hours',
            'Booked' AS 'Effort'
        FROM work.sapactivities 
        GROUP BY sapactivities.notification,sapactivities.activitytext,sapactivities.start

    UNION ALL

    SELECT plannedactivities.activitydate AS 'CurrentDate',
        /*CONCAT_WS(' ',resource.firstname,resource.lastname) AS 'Resource',*/
        resource.sapActivityText AS 'Resource',
        notification.notification AS 'Notification',
        2000000 + plannedactivities.hours AS 'Hours',
        'Planned' AS 'Effort'
    FROM work.plannedactivities
    LEFT JOIN work.notification ON plannedactivities.idNotification = notification.id
    LEFT JOIN work.resource ON plannedactivities.idResource = resource.id

) AS result
GROUP BY result.Resource, result.Notification, DATE (result.CurrentDate)
```